# What is \= in Swi-Prolog

Tags: prolog, unification

As I browse through the internet to find information about Swi-prolog, I happened to find \= , with given example like X \= Y. Can someone tell me what it is? Is it some kind of arithmetic operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic operator from Prolog, not specific to SWI-Prolog.

It means the left-hand-side term and the right-hand-side term do not *unify* (now and thus also in any future instantiation down this path of the search tree), so it is a question about the structure of those terms. You could also write `\+ (LHS = RHS)` instead of `LHS \= RHS`.

These do not unify:

```
?- a \= b.
true.
```

```
?- f(X) \= g(Y).
true.
```

But these do, so the answer is `false`:

```
?- f(X) \= f(Y).
false.
```

Instantiate on the right, still unify:

```
?- f(X) \= f(a).
false.
```

Instantiate on the left, unification is now impossible:

```
?- f(b) \= f(a).
true.
```

It may be interesting to use `dif/2` (`dif(X,Y)`: "ensure `X` and `Y` wont' unify down this path", which sets up a constraint involving its arguments that vetoes (and fails) any attempt to make `X` and `Y` the same.

After this, `X` and `Y` shall not unify. The residual constraint is printed:

```
?- dif(X,Y).
dif(X,Y).
```

Trying to unify `X` and `Y` after `dif/2` fails:

```
?- dif(X,Y),X=Y.
false.
```

Refining `X` to 1 is still possible:

```
?- dif(X,Y),X=1.
X = 1,
dif(1,Y).
```

Refining `X` to 1 and `Y` to 2 is certainly possible:

```
?- dif(X,Y),X=1,Y=2.
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

Refining both to 1 is not possible:

```
?- dif(X,Y),X=1,Y=1.
false.
```

Comment: So meaning that object X and object Y can only be interpreted in one-directional (not bidirectional) (?)

Comment: @Hingusan No, it means they must have different internal structure. It has nothing to with with the operator being symmetric. Indeed, `A \= B` <=> `B \= A`. Try it on the SWI-Prolog command line.

Comment: Nice answer with a good reference, good example and intuitive explanation to the dif constraint.